# kill my app process when exit the app by press back button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

In my app, I have only one **Activity** which hosts several **fragments**.

The layout of my **activity** is(`main.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout...>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder">
     </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My only **Activity**:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
       super.onCreate(arg0);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       //I dynamically add fragments into fragment_placeholder of the layout

       FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();

       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

       fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, FirstFragment, "first");
       fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }


}
```

I my above **activity**, I dynamically add the first fragment to layout. The other fragments replace this fragment accordingly.

I know when user press back button to exit the app, by default, my app will still run on **background**.

what I want however is to **kill the app process**  when user seeing the `firstFragment` and press the **back button** (exits the app). **But how can I kill my app technically(programmatically) in Android?**

Comment: I think we have to call finish() of activity to close the activity.

Comment: But does Activity closing really kill the app process ??

Comment: Activity will be closed, but the app's info. may be saved for fast startup of app for next time launches. see Android App life cycle available at Android Developers website for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up killing my app process by:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
```

Comment: It is not recommended. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon

Comment: I want know by doing this i will get push notification or not

Answer (score 2):

you can override the back button behaviour by using below code and kill your activity

```
          public void onBackPresed(){

                  finish();

                     }
```

Comment: Does finish() callback really kill the app  process ?

Comment: calling a finish(); remove the memory from Tasks and Back stack where all runing or pause app are store like Stack

Comment: I see, the thing is I dont want to back stack anything, that's why my post subject is how to KILL app.